# if int A[5] is declared then only A is pointer to the A[0].which means A is just a pointer . then how come sizeof(A) gives answer as 20

Tags: c, sizeof

Suppose if `int A[5]` is declared  then variable `A` will be  pointer to the `A[0]`. Which means `A` is just a pointer and `A` stores the base address of array `A[5]` . Then how come `sizeof(A)` gives answer as 20

Comment: Which language is this about? I presume C?

Comment: You should add the C or C++ tag so people can more easily find the question. Also, you can format small bits of code with backticks like `\`this\``.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is an array name a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-an-array-name-a-pointer)

Answer (score 2):

`A` isn't a pointer to the first element. It is an `int[5]`, or a five element array of ints (the size is part of the type). It can decay into a pointer to the first element when you do stuff like pass it to a function taking a pointer.

Comment: if A[10] is declared then why do this statements give same answer =>printf("%d", A[i]) and printf("%d", *(A+i));

Comment: @satya Using the subscript operator is one of the situations where the array decays into a pointer. `A[i]` is exactly the same as `*(A + i)` here.

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to what you might have heard, arrays are **not** the same as pointers.

In most contexts, the name of an array will *decay* into a pointer to the first element, such as being passed to a function or as the subject of pointer arithmetic.

One of the cases where this decay does not happen is when the array is the subject of the `sizeof` operator.  In that case the operator returns the full size of the array in bytes.

This is detailed in section 6.3.2.1p3 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> **Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator**, the _Alignof
>   operator, or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to
>   initialize an array, an expression that has type "array of type" is
>   converted to an expression with type "pointer to type" that points
>   to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If
>   the array object has register storage class, the behavior is
>   undefined.

Section 6.5.3.4p4, which details the `sizeof` operator, additionally states:

> When `sizeof` is applied to an operand that has type `char`, `unsigned char`, or `signed char`, (or a qualified version thereof) the result is
>   1. **When applied to an operand that has array type, the result is the total number of bytes in the array.** When applied to an operand
>   that has structure or union type, the result is the total number of
>   bytes in such an object, including internal and trailing padding.

If you had some something like this:

```
int A[5];
int *B;
B = A;
printf("sizeof(B)=%zu\n", sizeof(B));
```

You would get the size of an `int *` on your system, most likely either 4 or 8.

Comment: int A[5] ...then A[i] is equal to *(A+i).....because A which is array name points to first element i.e. A[0]....then why does "sizeof(A) "  returns 20 which is size of whole array??

Comment: @SatyaprakashYelgatte `A` doesn't point to the array because it is **not** a pointer.  `A` **is** the array, so `sizeof(A)` gives the size in bytes of the whole array.